# how can I read the document using php and store database in mysql with linux?

Tags: php

How can I read a Word document using PHP and store it in a MySQL database on Linux?

I'm using Ubuntu and PHP5.

Comment: There are a number of discrete tasks there. Which one is giving you trouble? And read the document from where? And what does 'read' mean? To put raw data in the database? Do you want to convert it to text? Do you want to extract meta data from it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some resources to look at

PHP upload form to send the document to the server
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

PHP download, this is how you from PHP tells the browser that the response you send is to be treated as a downloadable file.
http://snipplr.com/view/205/download-file/

Here is some tips for storing data in a MySQL database
http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx

Start by checking these out and then rephrase or add some detail to your question =)